# Bootstrap on visual Studio shows stacked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

[image]I copied the following code from Internet:(source http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Test Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I run this in  a.html file it works as seen in internet page. That is column 1 and Column 2 are in the same row.

Now if I copy the exact same code to VS 2013(using web application with one simple empty webpage) I see column 1 on the top of column2!

Please let me know if this works for you or not?

Comment: Please copy the above code to a VS studio and test it and let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Can someone please let me know if you can reproduce same behavior? Maybe VS bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it at my end and found it working the way it should work according to you.

Attaching image [HTML display of one row 2 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6IKG.png)

Whereas I tried by removing closing div from first column and I got the one column view that is first column on top of second column.

Attaching image [HTML display of overlapping column on top of each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPPLw.png)

If I am able to address and depict your issue, then please check the closing div  for first column.

Comment: As said I copied and pasted the code from the website. We closing div is there. So it does work for you?. What version of visual studio?

Comment: Yes, it does work for me. It's Visual Studio 2015, might be VS 2013 bug.

Comment: I tested on VS2015. Same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it took me more than 2 hours and I was looking all around the web to find a solution.

It turned out I had enabled `compatibility mode` in `IE`, so an old application can run.

Compatibility mode makes `IE` runs like `IE7` which is NOT fully compatible with the Bootstrap.

Thanks all who spend some time here trying to find out the answer!